# how to keep GCLID or add automatically UTM parameter after copying URL

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop, utm

one of my clients is facing huge problem with his store.
First of all lot of his clients are b2b clients, and many of them after spoting the right product in Google ads, are copying link to product and sending it to other person( usually accountant who is purchasing it). In this case im loosing GCLID from Google Ads and Google Ads is not receiving conversion data after such action.

Is there any way to make URL keep this GCLID parameter when user from this session is copying any link from this store, or is there any script, that can add UTM parameter to copied by user URL for users who came from google/cpc source and medium?

Shopping platform is Presta Shop 1.7
Im not sure if im asking in the right help, so sorry if for any inconvenience.